# Do lightsabers absorb blaster energy?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

Do lightsabers absorb any of the energy shot at them by a blaster, or is it all deflected away?

Comment: Lightsabers have been shown to absorb Force Lightning, so it is not out of the realm of possibility that they could absorb other energies too, like from deflected blaster bolts. I don't think any Canon material has really delved into that particular aspect of lightsabers, though.

Comment: "**deflected** blaster bolts" - that's kinda the answer right there. But what are "blaster bolts" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the energy from a blaster shot is reflected, and some of it is transferred to the light saber as kinetic recoil.  This is subtle but visible in *Return of the Jedi*.

How much energy goes into the recall, and whether there are any other modes of energy conversion besides reflection and recoil, is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, I would say that it deflects most "bullets". Most "bullets" are a single bolt, meaning that what we see bounce off the lightsaber appears to be the same. Therefore, I would assert that it is all deflected away.

Comment: Don't they supposedly fire plasma? I don't think the concept of an indivisible single bolt works with that. Not to mention that you could still absorb energy from it.

Comment: Not necessarily. While some guns use plasma bolts, they are still bolts. It is still evident that it is a single "bullet" of compacted energy. @Misha R

Comment: Plasma cannot be an indivisible unit by definition.  Nor is being indivisible part of the definition of the term "bolt."  Moreover, none of it tells us anything about absorbing energy.

Comment: It is not indivisible. However, the lightsaber doesn't divide things. We have to remember that a lightsaber goes through metal, plastic, etc. by melting it's way through. It's energy vs. energy, and the saber prevails and deflects the blast. @MishaR

Comment: Plasma is matter, not energy. Moreover, like I said, being indivisible or divisible  tells is nothing about absorbing energy from the bolt. There is no reason to assume it cannot do that.

Comment: We have the result. Therefore, it is logical that the lightsaber reflects the energy within the blast, reflecting the blast as well as there is no energy to propel it anywhere other than where the force wielder wanted it to go.

Comment: I dunno. Your argument is clearly not based on any kind of real-world physics, and it doesn't seem to have solid ground in Star Wars canon.  And, to be perfectly honest, it doesn't make much sense to me. But, in itself, it's no worse than any of the canon reasoning behind Star Wars stuff, so the lack of any science behind it would be fine if the franchise gave it as an answer. One way or another, it needs some form of backup to serve as an answer on here. Right now it isn't much more than your own fiction.

Comment: Star wars isn't real world. Secondly, we have the result, and we can compare these results to make an conclusion. That is what I have done here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you got to remember that lightsabers and blasters are pretty munch laser plasma weapons incased in a forcefield.  The problem here, is if you where just dealing with light the answer would be easy, but you are also dealing with a forcefield.

If you're​ just dealing with light blasters that have the same color and chemical,  the lightsaber would absorb the Blaster fire, which is what happened in *Star Wars: A New Hope*.  The Stormtroopers where shooting blue blasters at the lightsaber and Luke's lightsaber was absorbing it.  I think it may have to do with the color of the light more than anything.

Light rays of the same color will be absorbed by the object's color, but the rest of the colors would be reflected.  This is why you can see a blue circle, a yellow box or a red square.  The standard RGB which represents the 3 main colors and light ranges.  In that movie example the reason the blaster fire was reflected is the lightsaber was green and the blaster color was red.  I think the strength of the force fields also applies.